# Font awesome icon and input field borders overlap visible on mobile

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, box-sizing

On the login page there are font awesome icons in front of the input fields. In order to have a nice box border around both, I applied border property for both the icon and input field and removed the border-right and border-left respectively, so that it looks like a single box.

The issue I am facing now is when I switch to a mobile view, the border overlapping of both is clearly visible (please see the screenshot), but the desktop version looks good.
[image]

How can I resolve this border overlapping on mobile view?

Comment: Please add your current relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest putting both inside a div with border styling and disabling the border of the icon and the input.

Comment: could be one solution.

Comment: Took this approach, i know its quite simple. No idea why i was thinking in a complex way. Anyway thanks.